# How add correctly a .jar file in solr

Tags: solr

I want to add a new library in solr.

I copied the jar file in destination folder and I added in `solrconfig.xml` from 
`/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml`

and

`/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml`
link to destination folder like this

`<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/" regex="jts-core-\d.*\.jar" />`

where my file is `jts-core-1.14.0.jar`.

I restarted the solr but I don't have new functionality in my core.
What is wrong?

Comment: Are you using cloud mode? Does the log show that the library is being loaded?

Comment: I user solr in a docker container. In logs I don't find a line with information about this `.jar` around the `SolrConfig Adding specified lib dirs to ClassLoader` line. How I can identify exactly if is loaded or no?